# Ng animate in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need to show the div with animated effect .

```
 <div class="appdrawer pull-right tab-{{ showDetails }}" data-ng-click="showDetails = !showDetails; showDetails1 = false; showDetails2 = false;" >Apps</div>


<section id="workbench-apps" data-ng-class="{ 'hidden': ! showDetails }" data-ng-animate=" 'animate' ">
        <div class="rowfluid">
            Apps
            <div class="applist" data-ng-repeat="applist in applists">{{ name }}</div>

        </div>

    </section>
```

css

```
.animate,.animate-enter {
    -webkit-transition: 1s linear all; /* Chrome */
    transition: 1s linear all;
    opacity: 0;
    }

    .animate-enter.animate-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
    }
```

i tried with above code,but not working ,pls suggest a angular way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ngAnimate` is used (at least in 1.1.5) to add animation to an existing directive. If you check out the [ngAnimate documentation](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive%3angAnimate), you'll notice a list of supported directives. Use it in conjunction with one of these directives to get an animation.

Also, you're specifying that you want to use an animation called "animate." You'll actually need to define an animation with that name in the CSS.

Comment: @prash Read my answer again. `ngAnimate` only works for a short list of directives out of the box. You're attempting to use it with `ngClass` which is NOT one of the supported directives, so, of course, it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

As Jon7 mentioned, you can't use ngAnimate with ngClass in Angular 1.1.5. You can use ng-Show though.

Also, in Angular 1.2 ngClass based animations will work. Year of Moo has a great writeup with samples: http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html